# Test class error when executing on sandbox

Tags: apex, unit-test

> System. queryException: List has no rows for assignment to sObject

I get this error when a existing test class executes on sandbox. This is a old test class and haven't been updated recently. I ran the query and I can see rows are rendering when I run the query. Why still I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own test data to guarantee it exists. See the `Apex Developer Guide` (emphasis mine):

> ## [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)
>
> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage
>
> **Whenever possible, you should create test data for each test.** You can disable this restriction by annotating your test class or test method with the `IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` annotation.
>
> Test code saved using Salesforce API version 23.0 or earlier continues to have access to all data in the organization and its data access is unchanged.

Comment: Man has it been that long (api v24)

Comment: @Eric Yessir at the time it was surprising it took them so long, but yeah it's been "best practice" to create your own data for quite a long time now. They do a good job of prodding developers in the right direction. Hopefully they do something about unit testing in lightning to catch up.